# How do I identify adware when browsing Apple's App Store?

Tags: applications, security, ios-appstore, privacy

I'm new to iOS and setting up a new iPhone. Can someone please explain how to avoid [adware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adware) when choosing apps in the App Store? I will not install adware on my devices, and I'm happy to pay for apps that are free of any advertisements.

For context, here is a screenshot of adware in Google's Play store which clearly labels it as such:

[image: screen-shot of Google Maps app listing in Google Play]

And here is the same app in the App Store, which fails to mention ads:

[image: screen-shot of Google Maps app listing in App Store]

I'm looking to install a few games and so far I am unable to do so due to a lack of information...have I overlooked something?

Comment: Off the top of my head if the app offers "in-app purchases," making that purchase usually disables ads so that notation next to the "GET" button would be a likely sign of ads. Also if you check the reviews of the app it will often mention the ads. Unfortunate Apple does not provide that feature.

Comment: To build on @SteveChambers's comment, there's a dropdown next to the "in-app purchases" button.  From there you can see the purchases offered.  Often you'll see a "remove ads" statement or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not an equivalent in the App Store. 
If this is a feature you'd like to see implemented, [go here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) to leave product feedback.